# What are games without player interaction, like Progress Quest, called?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for games like [Progress Quest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_Quest) and [Idle RPG](http://idlerpg.net/) that contain very little interaction with the player, but can't figure out a genre to search for. What is the genre called?

I've tried "Zero-player games", but that term seems to be occupied by something else.

Comment: There's no standard genre name for this type of game yet I don't think, but I'd call it an `inaction game`, `passive game` or something along those lines.

Comment: Screensaver...?

Comment: @bwarner normal screensavers can hardly be called games, while PQ and IRPG can, even if everyone doesn't find them interesting.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say screensavers can't be games.  It gave me an idea for an edit to my answer :)

Comment: If it were me, I'd call them idling games. That's what I call my IRPG successor, anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not really a "genre label" for this kind of gaming, simply because non-interactive games aren't much of a game genre.  Most of the ones that exist are either silly idling games (Idle RPG/Progress Quest/[Idle 2](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Nabb/idle-2-konquest)), bots (like this one that [plays a roguelike by itself](http://www.thangorodrim.net/borg.html)), or more AI experiment than game ([Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), for instance).

I think that "[Zero Player Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-player_game)" or "bot game" is about the best you can do.  I did find some interesting articles when I searched for "[games that play themselves](http://www.foxnews.com/scitech/2010/11/19/nintendo-shipping-video-games-auto-pilot-controls/)."

There's also a subgenre of the strategy genre where you'll find games where you can only interact indirectly with the game world, with games like [Populous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populous) or Evil Genius.  This subgenre is generally called "[Artificial Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_life_game)" or "[God Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_game)".

Some games are capable of playing themselves, in a demo or "attract" mode.  Arcade games are especially fond of this, as it [attracts people](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qp8gcZKj_Jk) to the cabinet and shows them what they might get for dropping in a quarter.

If we consider things like ProgressQuest games, then screensavers might be considered non-interactive games as well (or in reverse, non-interactive games might be screensavers).  There was one screensaver for Win95 that [played a little maze](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL8JTQYH7l0), for instance.  Of course, there's also the iconic After Dark package that not only featured a number of things you might consider to be non-interactive games, but also some screensavers that were fully playable, like [Lunatic Fringe](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/10/03/blast-from-the-past-lunatic-fringe/).

Part of the problem is that we already have many non-interactive forms of digital entertainment.  We give them many terms, but one is "movie."  You could consider a movie like [Scott Pilgrim vs. The World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Pilgrim_vs._the_World) to be a "game that plays itself."  The protagonist even levels up, has extra lives, and fights a final boss.  Or, take the movie [Clue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clue_%28film%29), which went so far as to include multiple endings, and each time you went to see it there was a chance you'd see a different one.  (I realize that's tangential, but it's sort of an interesting aside to your question.)

"[Non Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-game)" is a similar term, but it's more for games that have no goal, like Mario Paint.  These games ride the line between game and application.

Answer (score 7):

On [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/idle-games), at least, they are called idle games.

Comment: Read that as "indie" the first time. o_o

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this kind of program would fall under the classification of a "simulation" - leave out any mention of "game" and you'll be more likely to find them in a search.

Comment: I can find neither IRPG nor PQ with such a search =/

Comment: Idle RPG will typically be categorised as an RPG from its title, and PQ is a joke about Everquest, hence it will typically be categorised as "Humour" or "Parody". I don't believe these categorisations will necessarily be applied to similar games.